# Trying to get primefaces dataExporter to show value of link instead of url

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use the primefaces dataExporter to export some data and I have a column that has a persons name and the name is a link to an external website.

Originally I had the following code and then I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=360) thread which says that h:commandLink is now supported by dataExporter

```
<p:dataTable var="inv" value="#{personBacker.investigators}" id="tbl" rows="50" effect="true">

    <p:column filterBy="#{inv.name}" headerText="Investigator" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputLink value="http://example.com/">
            <h:outputText value="#{inv.name}" />
        </h:outputLink>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Then I changed my code to this, but now the link doesn't take me to example.com. From what i found on the interwebs, the commandLink can only use an EL Expression I think.

```
 <p:dataTable var="inv" value="#{personBacker.investigators}" id="tbl" rows="50" effect="true">

        <p:column filterBy="#{inv.name}" headerText="Investigator" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <p:commandLink action="http://example.com" value="#{inv.name}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
```

How can I link to an external site using the h:commandLink or p:commandLink tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if my suggestion will work in your set-up with the *DataExporter* but to call an external link from a *commandLink/commandButton* I use the following in my set-up:

```
<p:commandLink value="external link" ajax="false" action="#{bean.externalLink()}" />
```

**Bean:**

```
public void externalLink() throws IOException {

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    // call external link
    String link = "http://www.google.com";
    ec.redirect(link); 
}
```

Another approach would be trying to set the link as *html*-tag directly. It schouldn't be too hard as for you showed in your code that the URL is already known:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">#{inv.name}</a>
```

I hope this helped, have Fun!

Comment: I tried setting the url in the html directly, but the dataExporter doesn't handle that correctly either. I'll give your first suggestion a shot.